# How to check external metrics data in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, hpa

I am using **DirectXMan12/k8s-prometheus-adapte** to push the external metric from Prometheus to Kubernetes.

After pushing the external metric how can I verify the data is k8s?

When I hit **kubectl get --raw /apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 | jq** I got the following result but after that, I do not have an idea how to fetch actual metrics value

```
{
  "kind": "APIResourceList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "groupVersion": "external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "resources": [
   {
     "name": "subscription_back_log",
     "singularName": "",
     "namespaced": true,
     "kind": "ExternalMetricValueList",
     "verbs": [
       "get"
     ]
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

actual metric value is fetched per instance, for example, the metric you attached is `namespaced: true`, assuming the metric is for pods, you can access the actual data at

```
kubectl get --raw "/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/wanted_namepsace/pods/*/subscription_back_log" | jq '.'
```

(or specify the pod name instead of *)

If you want HPA to read you metric, the configurations are (for example)

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: your-hpa
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: your-pod
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 10
  metrics:
  - pods:
      metricName: subscription_back_log
      targetAverageValue: 10000
    type: Pods
```

Comment: I believe the pods section in the URL is not required. See my answer for additional explanation and a working example on a similar external metric.

Answer (score 1):

The metric is namespaced, so you will need to add the namespace into the URL. Contrary to what the other answer suggests, I believe you don't need to include pods into the URL. This is an external metric. External metrics are not associated to any kubernetes object, so only the namespace should suffice:

- `/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/<namespace>/<metric_name>`

Here's an example that works for me, using an external metric in my setup:

```
$ kubectl get --raw /apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 | jq                                               
{
  "kind": "APIResourceList",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "groupVersion": "external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "redis_key_size",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": true,
      "kind": "ExternalMetricValueList",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```
$ kubectl get --raw /apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/redis_key_size

{
  "kind": "ExternalMetricValueList",
  "apiVersion": "external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {},
  "items": [
    {
      "metricName": "redis_key_size",
      "metricLabels": {
        "key": "..."
      },
      "timestamp": "2021-10-07T09:00:01Z",
      "value": "0"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: I get `Error from server (InternalError): Internal error occurred: unable to fetch metrics` when trying your solution. Also created similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77861109/how-to-get-value-of-external-metrics-in-k8s-and-prometheus-adapter